# Get total NetworkOut bytes per month for EC2 instance by instance-id using Boto3

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am not getting any metric after running the code , I wantto get total NetworkOut of an EC2 instance for a particular period of time.

I tried the below code:

```
import boto3
import datetime

client= boto3.client('cloudwatch')
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    MetricName='NetworkOut',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': 'i-instanceid'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-12 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    EndTime=datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-01-12 23:59:59", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    Period=300,
    Statistics=['Sum'],
        Unit='Bytes')
print(response)
```

OutPut Json:

```
{
    u 'Datapoints': [],
        'ResponseMetadata': {
            'RetryAttempts': 0,
            'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
            'RequestId': 'aefec967-16ad3732d23633c',
            'HTTPHeaders': {
                'x-amzn-requestid': 'aac-11e9-9aa7-732d23633c',
                'date': 'Sat, 12 Jan 2019 20:57:33 GMT',
                'content-length': '333',
                'content-type': 'text/xml'
            }
        }, u 'Label': 'NetworkOut'
}
```

Getting no value in datapoints

Comment: want something similar to this  ->aws lightsail get-instance-metric-data --instance-name Amazon_Linux-1GB-Virginia-1 --metric-name NetworkOut --period 2700000 --start-time 1488326400 --end-time 1490100240 --unit Bytes --statistics Sum

Comment: Did you substitute an actual Instance ID in `'Value': 'i-instanceid'`? **Tip:** If you use `--debug` with the AWS CLI, you'll see the parameters that were sent. Then, try and include those in your API call.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes I am updating the instance-is with the actuals ,

Comment: Also I tried the cli way but getting some errror command:aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2018-04-08T23:18:00Z --end-time 2018-04-09T23:18:00Z --period 3600 --namespace AWS/EC2 --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=InstanceId,Value=i-06c5e8ad784fe0c71 --debug

Comment: Error:File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/formatter.py", line 272, in get_formatter
    raise ValueError("Unknown output type: %s" % format_type)
ValueError: Unknown output type: None

Comment: Your `cloudwatch get-metric-statistics` worked for me when I substituted my own `InstanceId`.

Comment: It works for me now, I was putting the wrong "period" and date in which there was no datapoint..  @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Also it was not giving me metric as my instances were stopped, I was getting empty json, but cloudwatch dashboard shows metrics even when instances are stopped